# Rectangle issue loading dynamic text

Tags: qt, qml

I have a fairly large project I'm prototyping on RPI. I keep getting this error 'glGetError 0x501'. When I do one small rectangle with text in just goes completely black. This occurrence SEEMS completely random. It can work fine hundreds of times. When it fails I have to restart the software or reset the system. There are hundreds of similar rectangles in this project and this one is the only one that does this. Any thoughts or insights?

The code looks like this:

```
        Rectangle{
            id: modebox
            color: "transparent"
            radius: 0
            width: 100
            height: 100

            x:255
            y:410
            Text {
                id: modeText
                font.family: localFont.name
                font.pointSize: 30
                style: Text.Outline
                styleColor: "black"
                y: 15
                x:0
                function set() {

                    modeText.text = "MODE:  " + sensorValues.readAnalysisMode()
                }
            }
        }
```

Restarting and resetting the system.

Comment: Because you're making the `Rectangle` `color: "transparent"` you probably should migrate to `Item`. As to why you're leaking resources, it's not obvious from the code snippet. The only points I can see for further investigation are the font and style settings. I don't fully understand what you have there.

Comment: Also, consider showing us more code with regard to the lifecycle of the Rectangle. I would like to get a feel for how they're being constructed/instantiated (and destroyed).